# Will sap from wood ruin table saw or dust collector?

Tags: dust-collection, sap

In trying to repurpose 30 year old waterbed frame wood, I decided to turn it into 2x3s but when I cut it, it smells really sappy! I could smell it still hours later. I'm using it for basic support for a work bench (the bottom where wheels will attach) so I'm not concerned about sap leaking but I am concerned I just ruined my dust collector. The saw blade is sticky which I can clean, and the wood that got thrown up the top if the saw was sticky too. Any help would be appreciated as I'm super new to this.

Comment: I doubt you would have _ruined_ the dust collector. You may have gotten some sap stuck somewhere along the line, but it will quickly cover with dust and not be any stickier and not attract any other dust. It might catch larger pieces and cause it to clog more easily, but you should either be able to clean or replace a piece of piping that is causing issues. Note: I don't own a dust collector, so I'm speculating, hence, not an answer, just a comment.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Well, replying.

Comment: I'm quite surprised there hasn't been more of a response to this. As noted, I just made a comment because I don't own a dust collector (beyond the shop-vac that I use to clean up after it's hit the floor), so I'm not really certain.